# Where can I find canonical examples of radio communications at non-towered airports?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, radio-communications, non-towered-airport

I'm trying to find any canonical examples of radio communication patterns at non-towered airports. The FAR/AIM has very little in terms of sample announcements, etc. The AC-90-66B (https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_90-66B.pdf) doesn't offer much either. The best resource I could find so far is the "Say Again, Please" book by Bob Gardner, but I'm trying to find the guidelines from the "FAA's mouth."

Comment: Is AIM 4-1-9(g)(6) what you’re looking for?

Comment: avoid saying "taking the active" since there really is no defined "active" runway, despite what traffic may be currently using or wind may be currently favoring...

Comment: @StephenS, I'll take that as an answer. I read through that shortly before posting the question but somehow ended up thinking "there ought to be more on that," LOL. Seems to me, the subject warrants a decent Advisory Circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is **AIM 4-1-9(g)(6)**, recommended self-announce phraseologies. The self-announce phrases states **position, altitude, climb/descent, among other things** depending on the situation.

> **6.** Recommended self-announce phraseologies:
>
> It should be noted that aircraft operating to or from
> another nearby airport may be making self-announce
> broadcasts on the same UNICOM or MULTICOM
> frequency. To help identify one airport from another,
> the airport name should be spoken at the beginning
> and end of each self-announce transmission.
>
> **(a)** Inbound
>
> ***EXAMPLE−***
>
> *Strawn traffic, Apache Two Two Five Zulu, (position),
> (altitude), (descending) or entering downwind/base/final
> (as appropriate) runway one seven full stop, touch−and−
> go, Strawn.*
>
> *Strawn traffic Apache Two Two Five Zulu clear of runway
> one seven Strawn.*
>
> **(b)** Outbound
>
> ***EXAMPLE−***
>
> *Strawn traffic, Queen Air Seven One Five Five Bravo
> (location on airport) taxiing to runway two six Strawn.
> Strawn traffic, Queen Air Seven One Five Five Bravo
> departing runway two six. Departing the pattern to the
> (direction), climbing to (altitude) Strawn.*
>
> **(c)** Practice Instrument Approach
>
> ***EXAMPLE−***
>
> *Strawn traffic, Cessna Two One Four Three Quebec
> (position from airport) inbound descending through
> (altitude) practice (name of approach) approach runway
> three five Strawn.*
>
> *Strawn traffic, Cessna Two One Four Three Quebec
> practice (type) approach completed or terminated runway
> three five Strawn.*

Examples shown are from the [Aeronautical Information Manual](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap4_section_1.html). I hope that helps!